# Is there a maximum number of characters that can be written using a StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Is there a maximum number of characters that can be written to a file using a StreamWriter? Or is there a maximum number of characters that `WriteLine()` can output? I am trying to write some data to a file but all of the data does not seem to make it. This is the current state of my code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathToFile);

foreach (GridViewRow record in gv_Records.Rows)
{
    string recordInfo = "recordInformation";

    sw.WriteLine(recordInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you calling StreamWriter.Close() or Flush()?

Comment: Cause the AutoFlush property might be set to false.

Comment: @MagicKat: then you obviously wouldn't forget to call Flush, because AutoFlush must be explicitly disabled...I'd hope.

Comment: @itsmatt: I am looking at close in reflector, but I am not seeing a call to flush ...

Comment: StreamWriter.Dispose calls Flush (as per reflector), which is called by Close.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - autoflush, I believe, defaults to false.

Comment: @sixlettervariable: doh ... the Dispose I was clicking on was taking me to TextWriter.  My bad lol

Answer (score 8):

Be sure you wrap your StreamWriter in a using-block, or are careful about your [explicit management of the resource's lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx).

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"somefile.txt"))
{
    // ...
    writer.WriteLine(largeAmountsOfData);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are calling .Flush()